# Chinese segmentation selection in model loading in Spacy 2.4 release

Tags: spacy

For the Chinese model loading, how can I load all the models while still be able to set the pkuseg and jieba settings?

```
nlp = Chinese() # Disable jieba through tokenizer config options 
cfg = {"use_jieba": False} 
nlp = Chinese(meta={"tokenizer": {"config": cfg}})
```

The 'nlp' created by Chinese() doesn't have other models besides segmentation models. This can only load the segmenter models. If I do this to get the 'nlp' object:

```
nlp = spacy.load('zh_core_web_sm')
```

This loads all the models. However, how can I control the pkuseg or jieba parameters in this load function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to modify the segmentation setup in the loaded model.

It's technically possible to switch the loaded model from pkuseg to jieba, but if you do that, the model components will perform terribly because they've only been trained on pkuseg segmentation.

Comment: It makes sense. Then how can I pass user_dict parameter when I load all models by 'nlp = spacy.load('zh_core_web_sm')'?

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way to do it on loading, but you can use `nlp.tokenizer.pkuseg_update_user_dict()` to make changes after loading.

Comment: cfg = {"pkuseg_model": "default", "require_pkuseg": True, "pkuseg_user_dict": "/path"}: This is to OVERRIDE existing user dictionary, but nlp.tokenizer.pkuseg_update_user_dict(["中国", "ABC"]) is to APPEND new words to existing dict. Is this the difference of the two ways?

Comment: Yes. You can override it in `pkuseg_update_user_dict` with `reset=True`, see: https://spacy.io/usage/models#chinese